# Correct way to use UPDATE in postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to **Insert/Update** rows in Postgres through *psycopg2* in python.

The Inserts/Updates would happen in the below fashion:

1. Try to insert the data
2. If it fails, check if it throws IntegrityError (Duplicate primary key) and then run the update query instead.

For my case, it may so happen that there are **multiple updates** triggered on the same row. To handle this, I was using the *FOR UPDATE* to lock the row.

I could not find what would be the correct way to call the Update query such that:

1. The first update acquires a lock
2. Other updates on the same row wait for the lock to be released
3. On completion the lock is released and passed to the next update query

The update queries are triggered independently by different threads.

Is the **FOR UPDATE** sufficient to handle the above case?
Below is what I was trying to do:

```
try:
    conn.autocommit = True
    cur = conn.cursor()
    command = '''INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES ('A','B')'''
    cur.execute(command)
except psycopg2.IntegrityError as e:
    try:
        lock_row = '''SELECT * FROM table where column1='A' FOR UPDATE'''
        cur.execute(lock_row)
        command = '''UPDATE table SET column2='C' WHERE column1='A' '''
        cur.execute(command)
        updated_rows = cur.rowcount
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print(error)
finally:
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()
```

Also, should I be using `autocommit` or use  `BEGIN.SELECT.UPDATE.COMMIT` instead?
I am new to postgres so I could have done a lot of things wrong above, do let me know if there is anything else I should correct.

Comment: You could use [ON CONFLICT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) instead. It lets you do INSERT+UPDATE in atomic way using single query. No need for locks.

Comment: ON CONFLICT will solve the *INSERT and if throws error, Update* thing but for multiple updates happening on the same row, I would require a lock, right?

Comment: `conn.autocommit = True` - bad practice, use instead `cur.commit()`